# When evaluating code in 'Rscript' buffer, ESS switched the focus to the 'R' buffer

Tags: r, emacs, ess

When I open an R-script in Emacs with ESS and evaluate the code with `Ctrl-C-C` emacs asks me: *R starting project directory? ~/* for example if the file were in my home directory. Then I hit `enter` to agree and the code is evaluated in a new R process in a new buffer in emacs. However, a new (very annoying) behaviour is that the emacs focus switches to the new R buffer forcing me to navigate back to the R script buffer to continue working. This only happens when R is started the first time not subsequent times I evaluate code after R is already started.

Does anyone have a solution to this new (Mid 2020 perhaps?) behaviour in ESS?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to version **20210117.1706** of ESS from a version dated mid October 2020 removed this behaviour. Using emacs version **27.1**.